# NDSolve is not picking the correct initial condition

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a differential equation in mathematica:

```
a = 3.0; Tau = 100.0; T0 = 0.5; g0 = N[Tanh[2/T0]]
Gq = (1 - Sqrt[1 - g0*g0])/g0; p = -Log[Gq]
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
pde = D[G[y, x], x] == -2 z0*(1 - x)^(a )*G[y, x] +  D[G[y, x], y, y];
ic = {G[0, x] == 1.0, G[200, x] == 0.0,G[y, 0] == Exp[-y Sqrt[2 z0]]};
s = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {G[y, x]}, {y, 0.0, 200.0}, {x, 0.0, 1.0}];
c = LogLogPlot[0.5 (1 - G[y, x] /. s /. y -> 0.05), {x, 0.0, 1.0},PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
G[y, x] /. s /. y -> 0.1 /. x -> 0.0
Exp[-0.1 Sqrt[2 z0]]
```

Here, G[y,0] is the initial condition. When i am printing the G[y,0] (second last line of the code) and the actual value of G[y,0] at that point (last line of the code), they both are giving different answers due to which i am not getting correct answer from the Plot as well.
Where is the problem in this code, why it is not picking the correct value of the initial condition?

Comment: Your IC says `G[0, x] == 1.0` and `G[y, x] /. s /. y -> 0 /. x -> 0` agrees. Your IC says `G[200, x] == 0.0` and `G[y, x] /. s /. y -> 200 /. x -> 0` agrees.  What which IC is wrong?

Comment: G[y,0]==Exp[-y Sqrt[2z0]], say at y=0.5 and x=0, it is not showing correct value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a discretization problem. One needs to refine the spatial grid. One can see that the OPs `NDSolve` does in fact satisfy the initial condition, but only at 25 points. Between these points, there is interpolation error. You cannot really improve upon that if you keep the rough 25-point grid. There are several ways to affect the spatial grid, through precision/accuracy options and directly through [the method of lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) options. The `AccuracyGoal` option suggested itself to me because the exponential IC gets very small. I didn't think a setting of `20` would be high enough. Its success led me to understand the problem as centered in interpolation on the spatial grid.

```
s = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, G, {y, 0.0, 200.0}, {x, 0.0, 1.0}];
s20 = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, G, {y, 0.0, 200.0}, {x, 0.0, 1.0}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 20];
s100 = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, G, {y, 0.0, 200.0}, {x, 0.0, 1.0},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 100}}]

LogPlot[G[y, 0] /. Join[
    Solve[ic, {G[y, 0]}, 
     Complement[Cases[ic, _G, Infinity], {G[y, 0]}]],
    s, s20] // Evaluate, (* s100, not shown, looks like s20 *)
 {y, 0, 200},
 PlotStyle ->
   {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Dashed], Automatic, Automatic},
 AspectRatio -> 1/5,
 PlotLegends -> {"IC", "s", "s20"}]
```

[image]

The spatial grid length is the first dimension:

```
G["Coordinates"] /. First@s // Map@Length
(*  {25, 13}  *)

G["Coordinates"] /. First@s20 // Map@ Length
(*  {167, 13}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of machine precision. Rationalize all constants and increase "WorkingPresision" to e.g. 26

```
a = 3; Tau = 100; T0 = 1/2; g0 = Tanh[2/T0];
Gq = (1 - Sqrt[1 - g0*g0])/g0; p = -Log[Gq];
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
pde = D[G[y, x], x] == -2 z0*(1 - x)^(a)*G[y, x] + D[G[y, x], y, y];
ic = {G[0, x] == 1, G[200, x] == 0, G[y, 0] == Exp[-y Sqrt[2 z0]]};
s = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {G[y, x]}, {y, 0.0, 200.0}, {x, 0.0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 26];
c = LogLogPlot[1/2 (1 - G[y, x] /. s /. y -> 1/2), {x, 0.0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
G[y, x] /. s /. y -> 1/10 /. x -> 0
Exp[-1/10 Sqrt[2 z0]] // N

{0.964042}
0.964037
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing, In the code suppose i change 200 to 500 value, the value of initial conditions shouldn't change as they are independent of this value. But when i am changing it from 200 to 500, again answers are changing.

Comment: Increase working precision